# How to prove that there is no life undergound?

Tags: geologic-layers

Because humans can not reach the inside of the Earth, there might be possibilities like in some stories that there is life under Earth?

Comment: I think the premise of this question is incorrect. See: [Deep biosphere(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_biosphere). "It extends down at least 5 kilometers below the continental surface and 10.5 kilometers below the sea surface, at temperatures that may reach beyond 120 °C,[1] which is comparable to the maximum temperature where a metabolically active organism has been found. It includes all three domains of life and the genetic diversity rivals that on the surface."

Comment: 1.) You can't prove a negative. 2.) As the comment above suggested, there is life underground.

Comment: *"Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence."*

Answer (score 1):

The Kola Superdeep Borehole is [12.2 Kilometers](https://www.google.com/search?q=kora%20superdeep%20borehole%20height%20in%20kilometers&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS1020&ei=YzoNY7z7KOmIptQPpYWW4AU&ved=0ahUKEwj8uM3Bie35AhVphIkEHaWCBVwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=kora%20superdeep%20borehole%20height%20in%20kilometers&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCMggIIRAeEBYQHToHCAAQRxCwAzoGCAAQHhAWOgUIABCGAzoHCCEQoAEQCkoECEEYAEoFCEASATFKBAhGGABQ3QRY7yVg1idoBnABeACAAckBiAHAE5IBBjAuMTcuMpgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&safe=active&ssui=on). At the bottom of the Kola Superdeep Borehole it gets pretty hot, and there is no soil or much organic matter since it would probably have turned into oil on the way down due to pressure and heat.

> How to prove there is no life underground?

I get the impression that you do not think there is any life underground, however there is, there is life gathered in soil, rock and wood deep underground, miles underground that have biofilms with cells on them (Read Sandford Underground Research Facility's research on [this](https://sanfordlab.org/feature/life-underground))
Extremophiles exist, in bubbling boiling hot water on land so it would be reasonable to assume there must be some underground. However deep enough life cannot be supported anymore due to the following:

- Lack of food or nutrients to take in
- Heat rises (combined with lack of food/nutrients) will not encourage life growth
- High Pressure, unable to actually make its way so deep underground

So I conclude that life is available deep enough underground (couple miles down) and at a certain point life stops because of what I noted above.

Comment: Not so much density as pressure.

Comment: Per https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012821X16307555?via%3Dihub, the pressure is such that there's probalby no room for biological activity below about 2km. Even water can only form a film a few millions of a centimeter thick.

Answer (score -1):

It cannot be proven that won't be life underneath as if some day underneath material is exposed to the surface of the Earth, then will be very much possibilities of holding life on it. I'm talking about the future, but it's nearly impossible along the next 1 billion years an underground square kilometer not hosting life at least one time (unless if it's the material under the active currents limit layer), beneath it, if the temperature reachs a value major than the max. temperature DNA could resist then won't be the life we know, but it is not sure then if there could be another forms of "life" not based on DNA (like an advanced AI, more or less degree of "Intelligence", I'm not referring to AI as a conscious form of life, as it could be compared too with a program moving up or down depending of temperature, in fact we are this kind of form of life, but we do not understand how our brains work and that makes the difference).

Comment: In the statement, "... the max. temperature ADN ...". What does ADN mean?

Comment: @Fred I think it's supposed to be AND to emphasize the two parts.  Luis, suggest more proofreading and refining the writing as it's a bit unstructured and hard to follow currently.

Comment: Sorry, ADN for DNA in spanish, I forget acronym translations